# Как сделать auto-incerment в MongoDB (mongoose)?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

как можно реализовать чтобы при создании новой статьи, документу в MongoDB автоматически присваивался нормальный ID (сейчас этот ID выглядит так:
_id 65edcd75b3dadee8c987c933), и в дальнейшем, чтобы при создании статьи, их ID шли по порядку (от 1 до 1000 например).
Как это можно сделать?
Сейчас код выглядит так:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    date: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    viewCount: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    id: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
      required: true,
    },
    imageUrl: String,
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

export default mongoose.model("Post", PostSchema);
```

Comment: [Create an Auto-Incrementing Sequence Field](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v2.2/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/) - обратите внимание на Warning. [MongoDB Auto-Increment](https://www.mongodb.com/basics/mongodb-auto-increment) - также смотрите внизу полезные ссылки FAQ.